# Let $\frac{1}{2}<\cos2A<1$ and $6\tan A-6\tan^3A=\tan^4A+2\tan^2A+1$, find $\tan 2A$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, quadratics

Let $\dfrac{1}{2}<\cos2A<1$ and $6\tan A-6\tan^3A=\tan^4A+2\tan^2A+1$, find $\tan 2A$

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
6\tan A(1-\tan^2A)&=\tan^4A+2\tan^2A+1\\
12\tan^2A&=\tan2A\tan^4A+2\tan2A\tan^2A+\tan2A\\
0&=\tan2A(\tan^4A)+(2\tan2A-12)\tan^2A+\tan2A\\
\because\tan2A&\in\mathbb{R}\\
\therefore \tan2A&\leqslant3
\end{align*}
From $\dfrac{1}{2}<\cos2A<1$ gives $0\leqslant\tan2A<\sqrt{3}$

Alfter using 2 inequality, I still can't find the exact value of $\tan2A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We obtain:
$$6\tan{A}(1-\tan^2A)=(1-\tan^2A)^2+4\tan^2A$$ or
$$\frac{6\tan{A}}{1-\tan^2A}=1+\frac{4\tan^2A}{(1-\tan^2A)^2}$$ or
$$\tan^22A-3\tan2A+1=0,$$ which gives
$$\tan2A=\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}$$ or $$\tan2A=\frac{3-\sqrt5}{3}.$$
Also, $$\tan^22A=\frac{1}{\cos^22A}-1<4-1=3,$$ which fives $$\tan2A=\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the given eqn can be reduced to : 
$\begin{align} & 6\tan A (1- \tan ^2 A) =(1+\tan^2A)^2 \\ \implies & 6\sin A \cos 2A \sec^3A=\sec^4A \\ \implies & 6\sin A\cos 2A\cos A=1\\ & \implies 3\sin 2A \cos 2A=1\\ & \implies \sin4A=2/3\\ & \implies \frac{2t}{1+t^2}=2/3 \\\end {align} $, where $t=\tan2A$. Solve for $t$. 
 Can you take it from here?